# Is it possible to change the notification Dot's color on Android Oreo

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

Android Oreo has option to show notification dot for any new push notification. However, it is not documented anywhere whether it is possible to change the color of Notification dot programatically.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this color is taken based on app colors icon - probabbly most frequently used color.

[image]

Comment: thanks! is there any document you can point me to that mentions this? Basically, would be nice to be able to back my point since I need to explain it to other folks.

Comment: I am giving you one up. If you can provide any documents around this, that would be great, and I shall accept your answer as correct one

Comment: @Akshay I didn't saw any docs for it - I made some experiments by changing app main icon and I noticed what I wrote above.

During my experiments I targeted my app as Android M and next O - with different icons and result was same.

Comment: it's not working for me, it shows same color for all app